# How do I calculat the length of the cycloids?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate the length of the cycloids?

$\gamma :\left [ 0,2\pi \right ]\mapsto \mathbb{C} $ with  $ \gamma(t)=t-sint+i(1-cost)$.

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ applies $\sqrt{1-cos(2x)}=\sqrt{2}\left |sin(x) \right |$

What I did?

In this I would use curve integral.

$\int_{\partial K_1(0) }\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\gamma (t)}\gamma' (t)dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{sin(t)i'(1-cos(t))-cos(t)+1}{t-sint+i(1-cost)}dt$

But this looks weird to me.

I think I should use this $x\in \mathbb{R}$ applies $\sqrt{1-cos(2x)}=\sqrt{2}\left |sin(x) \right |$

or maybe I should define integral like:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-cost)^2+sin^2t}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-cost)^2+sin^2t}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(2-2cost}=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-cost}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x(t)=t-\sin(t)$ and $y(t)=1-\cos(t)$ we have $dx = \left(1-\cos(t)\right)\,dt$ and $dy=\sin(t)\,dt$, hence the element of length is given by
$$ dL = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = \sqrt{2-2\cos t}\,dt = 2\left|\sin\frac{t}{2}\right|\,dt $$
and the total length is given by
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}2\left|\sin\frac{t}{2}\right|\,dt = \color{red}{\large 8}.$$